# How to load information from database to a Label in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to load a data from a specific column in the database when a user clicks on a link button from the previous page.

I am using the `SqlDataReader` to do this, but I get the error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is my code:

```
private void loadDetails()
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select expectation from Tours where tourName ='" + tournameLb.Text + "'", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expectation", lb5.Text);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        lb5.Text = dr[4].ToString(); //I get error here 
    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Where

```
tournameLb.Text = Session["tourName"].ToString();
```

Comment: Try set breakpoint to see if you `SqlDataReader` is actually filled for a start.

Comment: Don’t concatenate strings to make SQL queries. You’re now vulnerable to SQL injection attack’s. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: I dont really know how to debug @Dimitar

Comment: Yes i know about this, I am only using strings so that it is easier for me to edit my mistakes. Once I get my problem solved I will switched to parameterized queries @maccettura

Comment: A more pertinent question is why you are using a DataReader to return a single record?

Comment: I just want to test it out with a single record in case I go wrong, if my single record works I will be adding more. @IrishChieftain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a parameter for the value, which is the good way, but you need to use a parameterized query with it:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select expectation from Tours where tourName = @expectation", con);
```

Also your query will only return one columns, but you're trying to get the value of the fifth column which doesn't exist:

```
lb5.Text = dr[0].ToString();
```

Alternatively, you can use the name of the column instead of the index:

```
lb5.Text = dr["expectation"].ToString();
```

Comment: i still get the same error, have edited my question with the line of code that I get the error from@Racil Hilan

Comment: Did you change the 4 to zero on that line like I said?

Comment: The "expectation" column is the fifth column in the database from the table. I am reading from the database. I used this method in my previous project before using only C# and it worked. @Racil Hilan

Comment: I don't know what you used before, but the query in your question is only selecting one column. It doesn't matter how many columns your database has, your query will only return one column. See my updated answer, you can use the name of the column instead of its index if you like.

Comment: ok, i get it now, i have changed the 4 to 0 and it works now. but now my label displays a row of lengthy text which is not what I want, how can I break the lines to go down to the next rows? such that the text gets displayed vertically instead of horizontally @Racil Hilan

Comment: This is a different question. Create a new question and add the code for your label and the text that you want to display in it so we can help you.

Comment: great. I have to wait for another 1.5 hours before I can post my next question @Racil Hilan. The codes I am using for that label is the exact same thing as the one i posted in this question. The output is just a row of lengthy text cutting across the webpage

Comment: How is someone supposed to know how to answer your "second" question without seeing your markup?

Comment: It is the exact same codes, but its fine I managed to solve it on my own @IrishChieftain

Comment: I was not asking for the code-behind, which I know is here in your question. I was asking for the code for the label in the aspx page. Also I asked for the text to see if it has line breaks or it is just a long single-line text that you want it wrapped to multiple lines. I'm glad you managed to solve it.